Is it possible to install ZFS on OSMC on Pi 4?
I've tried installing ZFS on OSMC, but when installing zfs-dkms with apt it fails to build because it cannot "build an empty module". The configure script is failing, and when following the suggestion to look at the make log it just says it couldn't find a makefile.
Since I've never used ZFS on OSMC to my recollection, I thought it'd be helpful to just know the answer to whether this should work. If it isn't then there's no point in troubleshooting further.
My goal was to import a pool created on macOS OpenZFS, which I can currently successfully do on x86 Ubuntu 24.04.

Glancing around online it seems the Pi kernel headers must be installed first, have you done that?

@goldilocks Thanks — yes, it complained about that so I did that first. It just got me to the current spot instead. Uninstalling, reinstalling, dpkg --configure... all results in the same thing; complaints of no kernel module being installed when trying to use ZFS tools like zpool.
